# Python subprocess in Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

I try to use "ren" command with Python 3.6.3 subprocess in Windows

Code:

```
import subprocess, os

path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Temp"

subprocess.check_output(["ren", os.path.join(path, "ABC.txt"), os.path.join(path, "Hello.txt")], shell=True)
```

but I get Error: "subprocess.CalledProcessError"

Please help!!

thanks

Comment: What error number does `CalledProcessError` indicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the ren command manual you can set only filename that you need to change current file not drive and folder:

try fixed code

```
import subprocess, os

path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Temp"

subprocess.check_output(["ren", os.path.join(path, "ABC.txt"), "Hello.txt"], shell=True)
```